# set range for column

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm using in my database, many fields of a certain range, like:

```
CREATE TABLE figures (
    deg FLOAT,-- between 0 and pi
    prc FLOAT,-- between 0 and 1
    .......
);
CREATE TRIGGER filter1 BEFORE UPDATE ON figures FOR EACH ROW SET
    NEW.deg=IF(NEW.deg>3.1415926 OR NEW.deg<0, OLD.deg,NEW.deg),
    NEW.prc=IF(NEW.prc>1 OR NEW.prc<0, OLD.prc,NEW.prc),
    ..........;
CREATE TRIGGER filter2 BEFORE INSERT ON figures FOR EACH ROW SET
    NEW.deg=IF(NEW.deg>3.1415926 OR NEW.deg<0, NULL,NEW.deg),
    NEW.prc=IF(NEW.prc>1 OR NEW.prc<0, NULL,NEW.prc),
    .........;
```

Is there any way to write it more clearly ?
Something like:

```
--CREATE PROCEDURE/FUNCTION between()..................
CREATE TABLE figures (
    deg FLOAT between(0,3.1415),
    prc FLOAT between(0,1),
    .......
```

At least, I don't want to write every filter twice. (ON INSERT,ON UPDATE)

Comment: Are you limited to MySQL? Looks like you just want a simple CHECK constraint but MySQL doesn't support them.

Comment: Thanks to "mu is too short". [w3schools here](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_check.asp) says that CHECK supported in MySQL.

Comment: @Dani-Br - It supports the syntax but it doesn't enforce them making them pretty useless!

Comment: Don't trust http://w3fools.com/ for anything.

Answer (score 3):

prior to MySQL 8.0.16 
    Triggers are the best solution
    Re:check constraints...

```
'The CHECK clause is parsed but ignored by all storage engines.'.....

'The reason for accepting but ignoring syntax clauses is for compatibility, to 
make it easier to port code from other SQL servers, and to run applications 
that create tables with references. '
```

lifted directly from: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/alter-table.html

From MySQL 8.0.16 though they now work as you would expect

```
  CREATE TABLE figures (
    deg FLOAT, 
    prc FLOAT,   
    CONSTRAINT `deg_min` CHECK ((`deg` > 0)),
    CONSTRAINT `deg_max` CHECK ((`deg` < 3.1415)),
    CONSTRAINT `prc_min` CHECK ((`prc` > 0)),
    CONSTRAINT `prc_max` CHECK ((`prc` < 1))
  )
```

Comment: The manual should read "make it easier to port code Incorrectly" since it will report no error for code that does not give the same results.

Answer (score 1):

> At least, I don't want to write every filter twice. (ON INSERT,ON UPDATE)

You can write a stored function and call that in your trigger.

```
DELIMITER $$

CREATE FUNCTION check_deg (degree FLOAT, olddegree FLOAT) RETURNS FLOAT
BEGIN
  DECLARE result FLOAT;
  result = IF(degree>3.1415926 OR degree <0, olddegree,degree);
  RETURN result;
END$$

DELIMITER ;
```

That way you have one point where the limits are defined and if anything changes you only have to change the boundaries in one place.

Answer (score 1):

The best solution is to use a CHECK() constraint, but MySQL doesn't support CHECK() constraints. (MySQL parses them, then ignores them.)

In some cases, you can replace a CHECK() constraint with a foreign key reference to a table that contains all the valid values. Floating-point numbers are *not* a good candidate for that kind of solution, though.

That leaves triggers. In your case, your best bet is to use a trigger that calls a stored function.

Answer (score 0):

I have a unfinished idea :

```
CREATE PROCEDURE check_constraint (table VARCHAR,field VARCHAR,condition VARCHAR)
BEGIN
    SET @update_trigger = CONCAT ("
        IF EXIST TRIGGER check_constraint_",table,"_",field,"
        BEGIN /*I don't know yet what to do*/ END
        ELSE /*IF TRIGGER DONT EXIST*/
        BEGIN
            CREATE TRIGGER check_constraint_",table,"_",field,"
            BEFORE UPDATE ON ",table," FOR EACH ROW SET
            NEW.",field,"=IF("condition, ", OLD.",field,",NEW.",field,");
        END
    ");
    PREPARE update_trigger FROM @update_trigger;
    EXECUTE update_trigger;
    DEALLOCATE PREPARE update_trigger;
    SET @insert_trigger = ..............................
END
```

After we  have a completed function, we can just call it during creation of the database:

```
CALL check_constraint("table","field","NEW.field<34567");
```

Answer (score 0):

try

CREATE PROCEDURE check_constraint (table VARCHAR,field VARCHAR,condition VARCHAR)

```
BEGIN
    SET @update_trigger = CONCAT ("
        IF EXIST TRIGGER check_constraint_",table,"_",field,"
        BEGIN /*I don't know yet what to do*/ END
        ELSE /*IF TRIGGER DONT EXIST*/
        BEGIN
            CREATE TRIGGER check_constraint_",table,"_",field,"
            BEFORE UPDATE ON ",table," FOR EACH ROW SET
            NEW.",field,"=IF("condition, ", OLD.",field,",NEW.",field,");
        END
    ");
    PREPARE update_trigger FROM @update_trigger;
    EXECUTE update_trigger;
    DEALLOCATE PREPARE update_trigger;
    SET @insert_trigger = ..............................
END
```